# jQuery AJAX - Get data from php during the request

Tags: php, ajax

I'm using AJAX to insert data in MySQL database. During the AJAX request, there is a PHP function that loops inside a JSON array in order to get data and to insert it inside the DB. Everything works fine.

But, I would like to know if there is a way to pass, during the AJAX request a PHP var to jQuery in order to append it in HTML or to retrieve the data with `console.log`. I can get these info on AJAX complete but is it possible to get info during AJAX request?

Answer (score 0):

Nope. HTTP is stateless. You make a request and you get a result.
You must use different techniques to check the request's processing advancements from server.

Given that you store a record of the progression during the processing somewhere (db, cache or whatever), the simpler trick is using another AJAX call to a simple function that returns the last processing record.
This is a traditional polling mechanism.

A more advanced solution could be using a different connection upgraded to websockets. This will be a true realtime channel.

On top of these there's a world of possibilities. It only depends on what you need to manage with your POST request and how long does it take the processing.

For big payloads it's usually better to return immediately and start processing in a different task. (and thus a pooling mechanism to check progression)

Comment: Thank you for your detail answer. My aim is to count the number of post inserted in the DB and also to get the name of the current post. The request can takes several second up to 45-60s. Do you have a concrete and simple example of what your are explaining? Thank you

Comment: No, cause i don't work in php. :) These are general concepts, you can find more online. Like topics on tracking uploads (upload is a different use case but imagine it as a long running server operation -> no different from your task) http://www.sitepoint.com/tracking-upload-progress-with-php-and-javascript/

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just echo the php var on the page?

E.g. `echo "<label>".$phpVarToAppend."</label>";`